# Image magic text writing on image dynamically

Tags: imagemagick

I am building a image editor with php, jquery, image magic, I am trying to write text on image dynamic position but not getting the exact command of image magic.
I tried imagemagic commands of writing text but these commands are for fixed position. e.g i need to write text on image "hey love" on position (x: 831, y: 38) x is width and y is height now what i need is exact command able to write text on dynamic positions.

convert temp.jpg -gravity North -pointsize 30 -annotate +0+100 'Love you mom' temp1.jpg

this command uses gravity i have dynamic positions

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
convert -size 400x250 xc:cyan -pointsize 18 -fill magenta  -draw "text 250,65 'Love you Mum'" result.png
```

[image]